# setState doesn't update state correctly

Tags: reactjs

`m` is a moment. `name` is 'startDate'. The two log statements often have a different output, although not always. How could this be happening?

```
handleDateChange = (m, name) => {

        let state = {};

        state[name] = m;

        console.log(name + ' ' + m.year());

        this.setState(state, () => {

            console.log(this.state.startDate.year());

         });
    }
```

Comment: Is `"startDate"` always the value of `name`? If not, they might differ. You could instead log `this.state[name].year()` and see what that gives you.

Comment: Can you give the whole component you are working in?

Comment: omg I forgot that moments are mutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clue was in the first sentence...

> m is a moment

moments are mutable and I was updating the `startDate` moment elsewhere in the app.